# Unit testing real server data exchange?

Tags: unit-testing, mvvmcross

I'm working on a project that has client and server side. And I'm writing a "pre-check-in" tool that will validate a lot of our communication between client and server.

I already have unit tests on both sides, now I really want to test the integration between both.
Like a real client connection to the server and vice-versa.

I really want to go unit testing on this, but I'm having a really hard time figuring out how I can initialize the MMVMCross framework and my view model classes.

In another thread I've asked for help on my "console app" that runs the tests but it is also really hard to initialize the framework and it makes me loose the coolness of unit testing with Visual Studio and reSharper.

My view models use SQLite and HttpClient with async/await.

For instance: I can't find a way to instantiate a view model that would need this interfaces:

`IChatService, IMvxMessenger, IDataService, ISettingsService`

Some from the framework some from my own code.
I known and I'm trying to register my ones, on a `TestFixtureSetUp`, but off course this fails, as the MVVM base subsystem (ioc?) is not setup yet.

Some above services, like `IDataService` for instance, also needs `ISQLiteConnectionFactory, IMvxMessenger, ISettingsService`.

I know unit testing is supposed to be fast, but my idea is to put all this tests in a new `Category`, that I would run only before my check-ins and my buddy, server developer, would run before his check-ins.

What would be the best approach here?
Any hint, suggestions, things to investigate/study would help at this point, as I'm practically stuck on this one.

Sergio

Answer (score 1):

> For instance: I can't find a way to instantiate a view model that would need this interfaces:
>
> IChatService, IMvxMessenger, IDataService, ISettingsService

Generally this would be done using Mock implementations and then calling the ViewModel constructor directly with those Mocks.

> I'm having a really hard time figuring out how I can initialize the MMVMCross framework

In order to initialise the IoC part of the framework you can use the `MvxIoCSupportingTest` helper class -https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Test/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core/MvxIoCSupportingTest.cs

If you then need additional parts of the framework, then generally you should mock these in some way. For example, see how navigation is mocked in these two articles:

- http://blog.fire-development.com/2013/06/29/mvvmcross-enable-unit-testing/
- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n29-testing-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html

---

If it helps, an example of this type of test is https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.Test/TwitterViewModelTest.cs#L21

---

If this answer doesn't have sufficient information, please provide a bit more example code about the tests you are trying to write.